# CSV data to array_map and str_getcsv using delimiter

Tags: php

My problem is I'm unable to pass 2nd parameter to `str_getcsv` function.

```
$rows   = array_map('str_getcsv', file($filePath_product_names_t), [";"]); 
            $header = array_shift($rows);
            $csv    = [];
            foreach($rows as $row) {
                $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }
```

**CSV structure**

```
"25";"some text"; "also some Text"
```

And also getting WARNING:

> array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of
>   elements

Comment: share the content of your $filePath_product_names_t

Comment: Exapmple : 

25;"Text";"Text"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599767/array-map-and-pass-2-arguments-to-the-mapped-function-array-map-argument-3 would help with the first problem.

Comment: Read the error message, it clearly states what the problem is.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
$rows = array_map(function($v){return str_getcsv($v, ";");}, file($filePath_product_names_t));
$header = array_shift($rows);
$csv    = [];
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}
print_r($rows);
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining the two problems, the first is that you can't pass a parameter the way you are trying in the `array_map()` so as in the link I posted in the comments, you can create an anonymous function to do this.

The second is that, in some cases a CSV file doesn't always have all the data for a row in the file.  In this case the header row and the other rows don't have the same amount of data, so use `array_pad()` to add blanks to make sure they do have the same length.  To combine these into the code...

```
$rows   = array_map(function($data) { return str_getcsv($data,";");}
    , file($filePath_product_names_t));
$header = array_shift($rows);
$csv    = [];
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $row = array_pad($row, count($header), "");
    $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}

print_r($csv);
```

Comment: Very helpful to have that array_pad part! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP >= 7.4 you can use [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) for a more concise syntax:

```
$rows = array_map(fn($v) => str_getcsv($v, ";"), file($filePath_product_names_t));
$header = array_shift($rows);
$csv    = [];
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}
print_r($rows);
```