# I don't manage to parse properly a CSV file with "|" delimeter using PHP

Tags: php, csv, parsing

I'm trying to parse a CSV file.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://flux.netaffiliation.com/feed.php?maff=3E9867FCP3CB0566CA125F7935102835L51118FV4';
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($url), ["|"]);
echo '<pre>'; echo print_r ($csv); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Here is a sample of what i get :

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5016488133494|Ary And The Secret Of Seasons PS4|100001|9.99||Jeu > PS4|https://xht.micromania.fr/?P3CB0566CA125FS1UD41282b0253295V4|https://edge.disstg.commercecloud.salesforce.com/dw/image/v2/BCRB_STG/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-masterCatalog_Micromania/default/dw65159733/images/high-res/100001.jpg?sw=1000|JUST FOR GAMES|JUST FOR GAMES|Explorez le monde merveilleux de Valdi !||new|4.99|||||||2
    )
```

Apparently, the parser doesn't take every "|" into account.

Comment: Perhaps some useful reading - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599767/array-map-and-pass-2-arguments-to-the-mapped-function-array-map-argument-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect your output, you'll notice that the split works on your first row. This is because (oddly) PHP only uses the extra args once per iteration, so you'd need to specify them for each row:

```
array_map('str_getcsv', file($url), ["|", "|", "|", ...]);
```

... which makes not a whole lot of sense to me, as you don't know how many rows you have. I'd just call it explicitly like this instead:

```
$csv = array_map(fn($line) => str_getcsv($line, '|'), file($file));
```

Or the older style:

```
$csv = array_map(function($line) { return str_getcsv($line, '|'); }, file($file));
```

Comment: Was going to suggest using `$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', ($ar = file($url)), array_fill(0, count($ar), '|'))`, but the arrow function is much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script I suggest. It assembles csvArray as result,  I hope you'll handle further:

```
<?php
$url='https://flux.netaffiliation.com/feed.php?maff=3E9867FCP3CB0566CA125F7935102835L51118FV4';

$file_name = 'csvToParse.csv';

$arrContextOptions=array(
   "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
); 

file_put_contents($file_name, file_get_contents($url, false, 
stream_context_create($arrContextOptions)));

$fopenCSVHandle=fopen($file_name, 'r');
$csvArray=array();

if ($fopenCSVHandle !== false){
     while (($data = fgetcsv($fopenCSVHandle, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) {
    //echo('<br />single row $data=<br />');
    //print_r($data);
    $csvArray[]=$data;
 }
    
//echo('<br />We got this $data from CSV:<br />');
//print_r($csvArray);
}

?>
```

Comment: If I understand well, you put the data from the URL to the file and then you put the data from the file to an array. Is it right ? Thank you, this method seems OK but there is some mistakes just after [4341][10] or [4345][10] for example. Don't understand why...

Comment: @Guillaume could you please make a screenshot of what you mean by error? or clarify with code you use or.. whatever gives error. Not really clear to me. And yes, the method you understood correctly. By the way, if i'm printing (print_r) the data, there's a tag loss in one of pieces of data and the rest of output goes crossed out. I mean, sometimes, in some cases, if you need pure text, probably it's better strip tags.... So please clarify what error you mean.